# Decimalformat in java

Tags: java, format, decimal

I am using `decimalformat` to format a value to 2 decimal places

```
Ex : 200.0075 --> 200.00
Ex:  200.0050 --> 200.00
```

The code i am using is :

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##")
```

Problem is

```
String value = df.format(200.0075) gives 200.01
```

and

```
String value = df.format(200.0050) gives 200.00
```

How can i get only 2 decimal places using `deciamlformat` in java.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  You seem to want both values truncated instead of rounded. Is that the case?

Comment: This is a lot more complex than it looks.  If you're starting with floating point values (float/double) you have a major gotcha that will get in the way.  You want to truncate at two decimal places, but since floating point is an inexact representation, you could input, say `200.17` and find out that the closest float is actually `200.16999999974` which would end up being `200.16` after truncation.  If all your numbers are `BigDecimal` from start to finish this problem does not exist.  If there are floats anywhere, you _will_ see unexpected results.

Comment: It would be immensely helpful if you would clarify if you are using floats and whether you can tolerate floating point artifacts like I described.  If you can't, then a more sophisticated approach is needed, and even then there will be cases that produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this rounding behavior because [the default rounding mode for `DecimalFormat` is `HALF_EVEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). Use [`RoundingMode.DOWN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN) instead.

Comment: That won't do what the OP appears to need, which is to truncate.

Comment: Won't work for `200.0075`, which will still round up. Only `200.0050` will round down.

Comment: Output is to zero decimal places in your example, not two.

Comment: Hm. http://ideone.com/EqtJHI I have concluded that the question is not well-posed, and it is late.